# error with NPM INSTALL

Tags: laravel, npm, vagrant

Estamos desarrollando una app en laravel, hemos creado un nuevo proyecto y tenemos un error cuando corremos NPM INSTALL dentro de homestead.

**Estamos usando:

- Vagrant 2.2.9
- NPM 6.14.10
- Node 12.20.0
- HOmestead en su ultima version

Hemos probado:

- Eliminando node_modules
- Eliminando composer.json.lock
- Limpiando cache
- Reinstalando homestead.
- Varios stackoverflows

No tenemos solucion.

El error que tira es:
no such file or directory open 'home/vagrant/code/testing/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/package.json.3695679736' This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

Alguna ayuda por favor?

Gracias.

Comment: Estas en SO en español, por favor traduce

Comment: This is SO in spanish, maybe you want [SO] instead or just translate it.

Comment: De casualidad no te falta instalar `cliui`? ¿Puedes agregar a la pregunta los contenidos de tu `package.json` en `home/vagrant/code/testing`?